# How to ORDER BY 'name + 0' in codeIgniter (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table in a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
id | name
1  | 1 some words
2  | 2 some other words
3  | 1.1 some other words
...
10 | 10 some other words
```

If I sort the table using following method:

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->order_by('name', 'ASC')
    ->get('table_name');
```

I receive the table in following order:

```
id | name
1  | 1 some words
3  | 1.1 some other words
10 | 10 some other words
...
2  | 2 some other words
```

But I actually want to receive the table in this order:

```
id | name
1  | 1 some words
3  | 1.1 some other words
2  | 2 some other words
...
10  | 10 some other words
```

This is possible using following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name ORDER BY name + 0 ASC;
```

But if I use codeIgniters query builder like this I get a database error:

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->order_by('name + 0', 'ASC')
    ->get('table_name');
```

Note that it is not possible in my situation to either store the numbers in a different column or order by id.

So is there a way to make this SQL statement work in CodeIgniters query builder?

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name ORDER BY name + 0 ASC;
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I am very sorry for the confusion but the '.' in 1.1 was not meant to be a floating point but as a dot like in: 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3
I have found a solution using @Marc B solution and put it into the query builder like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('name+0  AS name', FALSE)           
    ->order_by('name', 'ASC')
    ->get('table_name');
```

Thank you all very much for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a derived field and an alias?

```
SELECT name+0 AS fakename ...
ORDER BY fakename
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should order by the number first then by the text.

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := '1.1 some other words';

SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',1)+0 AS numberPart,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',1),-1) AS textPart;
```

**Output:**

```
numberPart     textPart
   1.1         some other words
```

---

Here's the full query:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM database_name.table_name 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1)+0,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1),-1);
```

<kbd>[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5893a7/1/0)</kbd>

or you can try casting the number string to decimal type.

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5893a7/4/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->order_by('CAST(name AS DECIMAL(10,6)) ASC')
         ->get('table_name');
```

Comment: thanks this brought me a bit closer to a solution bt I received following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC, 6)) ASC' at line 6

SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY CAST(name AS DECIMAL(10 ASC, 6)) ASC

Comment: recognizes the comma with column change  :C and this ¿  ->order_by('CAST(name AS DECIMAL(10,6)) ASC') ?

Comment: I see you interpreted the '.' in 1.1 as a floating point number, I am very sorry for the confusion but this was actually meant as a dot like 1.1.1, 1.1.2, ...
I have found a method that works using @Marc B solution and put it in a query builder, I will edit his answer with the query builder I wrote.

Comment: I no thought there could be a second level , why not use php directly?

Comment: In my opinion it is more practical to work with CodeIgniters query builder since it automatically escapes the values that someone submits which helps to prevent SQL injection. Of course the example above is simplified but there actually is also user input in the query. Also I think it is easier to read and easier to write than using php directly.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the first string (following [@1000111's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026008/17242583)) and `CAST` it to `DECIMAL` with one decimal place:

```
SELECT id
     , name
  FROM table_name
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1) AS DECIMAL (8,1))
;
```

In CodeIgniter, it looks like this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->order_by('CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1) AS DECIMAL (8,1))', 'ASC')
    ->get('table_name');
```

If you have titles with more decimal places, then change the DECIMAL definition. For example, if you have 1.15 and 1.17, then you need two decimal places, so you'd change it to DECIMAL(9, 2).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->db->order_by('fieldname + 0 ','',false,false);
```

This worked for me on Codeigniter version 3

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->order_by('sum(fieldname)', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->order_by('CAST(fieldname AS SIGNED) ASC');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.